# ASP.NET MVC OnActionExecuted ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I trying to check if an exception has been raised by an action with the **filterContext.Exception** below:

```
 public class Test : ActionFilterAttribute
    [...]   
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
            {
                if (filterContext.Exception != null)
                {
                     continue;
                }
            }
```

in controller:

```
        [Test]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Login(Usuarios usuario)
        {
            try
            {
             throw new Exception();
            }
           catch
           {

           }

         }
```

The **filterContext.Exception** is always null.I can't catch this information here.

Any ideias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the exception never escapes the action method since it gets caught as soon as you throw it. I'm surprised that your code compiles since you don't have a return statement. Anyway, try this action method:

```
[Test] 
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] 
public ActionResult Login(Usuarios usuario) 
{ 
     throw new Exception(); 
}
```

Comment: @Kirov yes it does, as asked by the OP in reference to MVC2. Unless you are referencing a completely different scenario, in which case I don't know what you are talking about.